# Fit book title in already defined image frame

Tags: javascript, php, image, autoscaling

I want to fit all my book titles using php/javascript in any of the below image like example.
Is it possible to scale image according to the book cover design automatically?

**Example:**

[image]

This book title how to adjust according to the below designs?

[image]

**In any of style whichever i will choose.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: @KenLee its not text. i have all the images designed already for thousands of books.so i want to fix those book titles in front of any book cover design?

Comment: It all depends on the original image of the book (front, side or back) that you take. If the original image looks correct (book cover centered nicely within the photo frame), there shouldn't be any problems with using the image frame from my experience.